# How to limit length of total words to read from a txt file

Tags: python, string, file

I have been trying to read a text documents easily using the code below, however I don't want to read the
entire text documents, let's say the total length of the words in the text documents is 2,845.

```
for line in open('foo.txt', "r"):
        print(line)
```

i want to read the first 1,674 words from the documents

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: Words or lines? Python would read lines, and you would essentially need a word counter which stops reading once the `n_words` reach 1674

Comment: words, thanks  @pisal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should always use `with open()` to open and read a file, as the file gets closed automatically. In total it's less error prone and more readable.

Concerning your problem, here is a short snippet which should push you forward:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'r') as file:
    text = file.read().replace('\n', ' ')
    words = text.split(' ')
    char_limited_text = ' '.join(words[:1674]
```

The above code works in three steps:

1. It reads the whole text of the file into variable `text`
2. It splits the text by single whitespaces
3. Joining the words back together, but only taking the first 1674 words

If performance counts, there might be a better solution reading the file line by line and to keep track of how much words are read in already.